# Pull-back of a smooth (covariant) tensor field is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, pullback

I want to prove the statement in the title. To be more precise and fix the notation, let $F: X \to Y$ be a differentiable map between smooth manifolds and $A$ a $k$-covariant tensor field over $Y$. The pullback $F^\ast A$ is a $k$-covariant tensor field over $X$ defined by $$(F^\ast A)_{p}(S_1, \ldots, S_k)=A_{F(p)}(T_p S_1, \ldots , T_pS_k)$$ for every $S_1, \ldots, S_k$ in $T_pX$.

My idea was to work in local coordinates, but I'm doing something wrong. Suppose we can write $A$ locally as $$A=A_{j_1, \ldots, j_k} \,dy^{j_1} \otimes \ldots \otimes dy^{j_k}$$ in a coordinate chart $(V, \psi=(y^j)_{j=1}^n)$ with smooth coefficients $A_{j_1, \ldots, j_k}$, then I would like to prove that the coefficients of $F^\ast A$ are also smooth. But how to identify them (which is a problem of its own interest to me)? And also, is this general local expression for $A$ on $Y$ correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pull-back of tensor fields plays nicely with the tensor product, and pull-back also plays nicely with the exterior derivative (make sure you prove these facts first), and pull-back of real-valued functions is simply composition: $F^*g = g \circ F$. Also, yes, that is the general local expression for $A$ on $Y$.

Now, if we take a chart $(U,\phi = (x^1,\dots, x^m))$ on $X$, such that $F(U)\subset V$ (or atleast $F(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset$) then
\begin{align}
F^*A &= F^*(A_{j_1 \dots j_k}) \cdot F^*(dy^{j_1}) \otimes \cdots \otimes F^*(dy^{j_k}) \\
&= (A_{j_1\dots j_k} \circ F) \cdot d(y^{j_1}\circ F) \otimes \cdots \otimes d(y^{j_k}\circ F) \\
&= (A_{j_1\dots j_k} \circ F) \cdot 
\left[\dfrac{\partial (y^{j_1}\circ F)}{\partial x^{i_1}} dx^{i_1}\right] \otimes 
\cdots \otimes
\left[\dfrac{\partial (y^{j_k}\circ F)}{\partial x^{i_k}} dx^{i_k}\right] \\
&= \left[(A_{j_1\dots j_k} \circ F) \cdot 
\dfrac{\partial (y^{j_1}\circ F)}{\partial x^{i_1}} \cdots 
\dfrac{\partial (y^{j_k}\circ F)}{\partial x^{i_k}} \right]
 dx^{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{i_k}
\end{align}
(throughout, the $j$'s range over $\{1,\dots, n\}$ and $i$'s range over $\{1,\dots, m\}$, and summation convention is used).

Using smoothness of $A$ and $F$, what can you now deduce about smoothness of $F^*A$?

Comment: Well I haven't already studied exterior derivatives. Where do you use the fact you mention? In the equality $F^\ast (dy^{j})= d(y^jF)$?

Comment: @arnett yes. $F^*(dy^j) = d(F^*y^j) = d(y^j \circ F)$; the proof is just a direct calculation by using the definition of $dy^j$ and $F^*$.